# Maintaining transaction in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have two tables `tblSOTransaction` and `tblSOTranasactionDet`.

Database operation are being handled using different stored procedures for both tables.

How to maintain a **single transaction** between different calls to different stored procedures in both tables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute both stored procedures inside one single transaction.

So, basically you have to follow these steps:

- Open transaction
- try
- Execute stored procedure 1
- Execute stored procedure 2
- commit transaction
- catch -> rollbak transaction

Comment: i am using Four Methods                                             1. method to create SqlTransaction instance of C# to begin Transaction                                                        2. To insertion/Updation in tblSOTransaction With Call to SP 1                               3. To insertion/Updation in tblSOTransactionDet With Call to SP 2                       4. To CommitTransaction                                            In Case of Exception, have also added Rollback instance...        But Following Scenario in not being implemented...